# A good translation for moonlighting

Tags: traducción

What is a good translation for `moonlighting`?

I've seen 'pluriempleo' used, but only ever as a noun, whereas in English we often use it as a verb, as in:

> I'm a biologist, but I moonlight as a science journalist.

Is there such a way to translate moonlighting into Spanish as a verb, or must it always remain a noun, making a translation of the above sentence something like:

> Soy biólogo pero tengo un pluriempleo como periodista científico.

Mil gracias!

Comment: I wouldn't use the term "tengo un pluriempleo como". It's easy to understand and I think it's correct, but sounds weird; I'd better use "estoy pluriempleado, trabajando también como".

Also, following Diego's answer, you can use the verb "compaginar": "Soy biólogo pero lo compagino con el periodismo científico".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que "moonlighting" se describe como

> Working a second job, in particular one after normal business hours in the evening or night.

`pluriempleo` es una de las mejores traducciones posibles. Dependiendo del contexto puedes querer usar algo no relacionado el tema laboral. A mi alguien me dijo una vez "[John and Jane Doe] who also moonlight as my parents". Sería raro decir que se *pluriemplean* como padres, ya que no es realmente un oficio. En este contexto yo optaría por algo como:

> [John and Jane Doe] también conocidos como mis padres.

En los ejemplos que das, si no quieres emplear el término "pluriempleo" podrías decir:

> Soy biólogo pero también hago de periodista científico.
>
> Soy biólogo pero también actúo como periodista científico.

Comment: Please note that "*actuar como/hacer de*" sound pretty much like "*hacer las veces de*", implying that the person is not actually, in this case, a science journalist. To indicate he is, I think we should use something like "*trabajar como/desempeñarse como (en su tiempo libre)*".